# Jquery issue with calling a function again - scope issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure how to fix this function but i am trying to have the function ifthenCheck(); to be called in one function and another that needs to run the code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am new to jquery so sorry if the code is sloppy but I have two drop downs that i check the value and save them. Then i modify the values a tad. But i need to make sure that the If then function is ran on both onchange functions. I hope this is clearer.

The code runs find on the bottom function because it is in local scope but this function it does not run at all -`$("#pa_color").on('change', function ()`

Thanks in advance as i am trying to learn this all.

I did make a quick jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/facjg19e/1/
Here is the code

```
    <script >
$(document).ready(function() {
    //line 1 adding attributes
    $("#input_3_11").attr("maxlength", "15");

    //line 2 adding attributes
    $("#input_3_12").attr("maxlength", "10");

    //line 3 adding attributes
    $("#input_3_13").attr("maxlength", "10");

    //line 4 adding attributes
    $("#input_3_14").attr("maxlength", "10");

    //$("#input_3_28").val(originalSKU);


    //Get the SKU number from color drop down
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#pa_color").on('change', function() {
            var originalSKU = $(".sku").text();
            var strippedSKU = originalSKU.substring(0, originalSKU.length - 3);

            console.log(originalSKU);

            console.log(strippedSKU);

            ifthenCheck();

            $("#input_3_23 ").on('change', function() {
                var selectedDropDownValue = $("#input_3_23 option:selected").val();
                ifthenCheck();

                function ifthenCheck() {
                    if (selectedDropDownValue == "aces_up") {
                        var updatedSKU = "206";

                    } else if (selectedDropDownValue == "atomic") {
                        var updatedSKU = "122";
                    } else {
                        alert('no values selected');
                        return false;
                    }
                    console.log(strippedSKU + updatedSKU);

                    $("#input_3_28").val(strippedSKU + updatedSKU);


                } //end if then function
            });

        });

    }); //end change function

}); //end first function - must have
</script>
```

Comment: If everything in the script is already wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` callback, why are you doing that again?

Comment: are you changing `#pa_color` anywhere? Your function will only run when something changes.

Comment: It's usually wrong to bind one event handler inside another event handler. Every time the user changes `#pa_color`, it will add an additional `change` handler to `#input_3_23`, so that handler will be run multiple times.

Comment: Can you provide your sample on JSFiddle?

Comment: well I have two drop downs so sometimes they go back and change both of them. Like i said i am new to this and thought that was the best way as then i have to check the values and make a new SKU number based on the two drop down choices.

Comment: please post some HTML so we can see where the problem is

Comment: You can access parent's function inside child but not child's function inside parent.

Comment: Here is jsfiddle. I am sorry but with my limited knowlege it is hard to know what to do. ..if you notice when you change the drop down color black , etc it does not change the output box as it stays the same...updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/facjg19e/1/

Comment: added jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/facjg19e/1/

Comment: anyone have any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your script a bit. See if this works for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//line 1 adding attributes
$("#input_3_11").attr("maxlength", "15");

//line 2 adding attributes
$("#input_3_12").attr("maxlength", "10");

//line 3 adding attributes
$("#input_3_13").attr("maxlength", "10");

//line 4 adding attributes
$("#input_3_14").attr("maxlength", "10");

//$("#input_3_28").val(originalSKU);


//Get the SKU number from color drop down

    $("#pa_color").on('change', function() {
        var originalSKU = $(".sku").text();
        var strippedSKU = originalSKU.substring(0, originalSKU.length - 3);

        console.log(originalSKU);

        console.log(strippedSKU);

        ifthenCheck();

        $("#input_3_23 ").on('change', function() {
            var selectedDropDownValue = $("#input_3_23 option:selected").val();
            ifthenCheck();


        });

    });
function ifthenCheck() {
                if (selectedDropDownValue == "aces_up") {
                    var updatedSKU = "206";

                } else if (selectedDropDownValue == "atomic") {
                    var updatedSKU = "122";
                } else {
                    alert('no values selected');
                    return false;
                }
                console.log(strippedSKU + updatedSKU);

                $("#input_3_28").val(strippedSKU + updatedSKU);


            } //end if then function


 }); //end first function - must have
```

Comment: An explanation  as to what you did and why would help. Just rearranging code and making people play `spot the difference` is not a high quality answer

Comment: It gave me an error saying selectedDropDownValue  is not defined. I did have to put another end }); right above the end first function to even work

Comment: @matthewmoore I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/facjg19e/2/) See if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have declared the global variables that would be needed across the functions. Also separated the change event handlers for both the dropdowns. This would pretty much give you the result you are looking for. However, let me know if you are looking for something more.